# Case sensitive search in Serenity plate form using Oracle

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript

I'm using serenity grid with Oracle database, the problem I'm facing is that Oracle is case sensitive and the grid search is only showing the rows which are match the typed text.

What type of changes I should do to convert the search text and the column data to lowercase?

Thanks

Comment: The serenity-js tag seems to indicate that you're using the [Serenity/JS acceptance testing library](https://github.com/jan-molak/serenity-js), is that the case or is the question tagged not as you intended?

Comment: @JanMolak it was by a mistake, I want to add serenity platform, but serenity-js come up.

Comment: @volkanceylan please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MyOracleDialect : OracleDialect, ISqlDialect
    {
        bool ISqlDialect.IsLikeCaseSensitive
        {
            get { return true; }
        }
    }
```

SiteInitialization.cs:

```
SqlConnections.GetConnectionString("Default").Dialect = new MyOracleDialect();
```